# Deriving the parameter $\exp(\eta)$ in eq. (2.9) from "Illustrative example of Feynman’s rest of the universe"

Tags: potential-energy, hamiltonian-formalism, geometry, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

I'm working on research on the *Entanglement in Coupled Harmonic Oscillators* when I stumble upon the research paper *"Illustrative example of Feynman’s rest of the universe"* https://doi.org/10.1119/1.19192

On the 2nd page of the paper, there are 2 parameters, $K$ and $e^\eta$ on *equation (2.9)*.

[image: Partial screenshot of page 2]

I manage to figure out that parameter **$K$** is the determinant for the matrix of the potential energy portion of the Hamiltonian of the *equation (2.1)*. I utilised the *equation (2.8)*, drew a right-angled triangle and derived the hypotenuse with the Pythagorean Theorem.

[image: Pythagorean Theorem]

I could only find some loose connections for the 2nd parameter which is **$e^\eta$**. A part of the numerator of the parameter is the hypotenuse of the triangle and the denominator of the parameter is **$2K$**. But, this doesn't help much.

Later, I thought the parameter, **$e^\eta$** might have a connection with *Hyperbolic Trigonometry*. So, I read through a paper, *Trigonometry in the Hyperbolic Plane*
by *Tifani Traver*. I came across **The Angle of Parallelism** on page 10 of the paper. *Equation (4)*,  **$\tan \frac{\alpha}{2} = e^{-d}$** seemed to be promising, where I replaced **$d$** with **$\eta$**. I tried to derive the parameter, **$e^\eta$** using this relationship I just found. Anyway, I am still unable to find the rationale behind the existence of the parameter, **$e^\eta$** in *equation (2.9)*.

Thus, my question is; Am I on the right track to derive the parameter **$e^\eta$**?. If I am on the right track, how am I to proceed? If I am off track, can anyone please lead me to the correct path? I am very confused.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a definition of $e^\eta$?

Comment: I edited the symbols accordingly. I am so sorry that I have no definition of $e^\eta$, that's why I'm here for some clarification. Thanks.

Comment: This formula is the definition of Eta. It doesn't have to have a meaning, its purpose is to decouple the terms in the Hamiltonian leading to 2.10. If you start with the task of decoupling the hamitonion I presume you would reach that result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. Really appreciate them.